# how can i show specific values in the combobox based on the checkbox state

Tags: vb.net

I want to show related values in the combo box when the user selects the checkboxes.

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        ComboBox3.GetItemText("10")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        ComboBox3.Items.Add("20")
    End If
End Sub
```

Any code suggestion?

Comment: The code you showed will do what it says. If that isn't what you actually want then you need to provide a much better explanation of the problem. As with all code, you need to put it in the right place to have it executed at the right time but you made no effort to tell or show us where that code is, so we can only guess. Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Spend some time reading in the Help Center to learn what that means. That you have no badges indicates that you didn't even bother to take the tour when prompted at registration.

Comment: question says what I want. To give more infor: check box is used to select the type of the shape ( square  ), when the user selects the checkbox, combo box  should be displaying the corresponding sizes only. another checkbox is used to select the round shape. the same combo box should be displaying the corresponding round shape sizes. Any code suggestion?

Comment: The description in the question is inadequate. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please update the question with a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the `CheckedChanged` event, you may use the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If sender.Text = "Select 10" Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "10"
    Else
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "20"
    End If
End Sub
```

This is coded only for two CheckBoxes. The `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` tries to find if there's an option given in the string available in the ComboBox control. An example output is given:

[image: CheckChanged]

Hope it helps!